# HTML Object - Make a custom pause/play function

Tags: jquery, html, flash

Good day.

So I have this object code for a player.swf and it plays an online radio. I want to be able to make a pause/play button for it but I don't know how.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf" width="1" height="1" id="radioPlayer" style="visibility: visible;">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="flashvars" value="duration=9999&amp;file=http://john.caster.fm:31433/listen.mp3?authne58b540a15b87455faa7c768dd8fc024&amp;provider=sound&amp;volume=70&amp;autostart=true">
</object>
```

How would I go about making a play/pause button for this? I saw some other alternatives but didn't understand the concept behind them.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: That'a not an HTML object, that's a Flash movie. It's inside the SWF. You need the FLASH source code to make changes to it.

Comment: Preferably I want to make the pause button through Javascript. So it's a href or a button

Comment: Unless the SWF has deliberately exposed the JavaScript interface, you are out of luck.

Comment: D: Would there be any way to get around this? I just need it to be a player.

Comment: Pick a player that has documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a little example for you. I didn't try it out but it should work, because javsacript should recognize the flash object as a media object, which comes with some defined functions.

**Beware:** the javascript part in the onclick event of the buttons contains a qualifier which needs to be the id of the specified media object in your case it is **radioPlayer**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf" width="1" height="1" id="radioPlayer" style="visibility: visible;">
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="flashvars" value="duration=9999&amp;file=http://john.caster.fm:31433/listen.mp3?authne58b540a15b87455faa7c768dd8fc024&amp;provider=sound&amp;volume=70&amp;autostart=true">
    </object>
    <p>
        <button onclick="document.radioPlayer.Play()">Play</button>
        <button onclick="document.radioPlayer.StopPlay()">Pause</button>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. I checked the console and no errors were given out however.